# Running some memory analysis as part of Android CI

Tags: android, continuous-integration, profiling

Need some pointers/ideas to compute baseline and some basic memory stats on Android App in automated fashion as part of CI.

Anyone has tried doing it through tests? Any lessons learnt? I am aware of coverage analysis plugins but not of any plugin that could help compute memory footprint of a certain APK in specific scenario.

Goal would be not necessarily pin point where the issue is but help flag the memory consumption of app has increased/decreased, see a trend and help signal a possible issue and needs digging in further

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to profile your app manually.Do an activity repeatedly and use memory walkthrough, heap viewer and allocation tracker together to find issues.

However, if you must do it via CI(AFAIK there is no available plugin), There are two ways to go about it:

**1) Run your CI UI test cases and take dumpsys:**

Take dumpsys at the beginning of test, after every TC and at end of every TC:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ADB_PATH,"shell","dumpsys meminfo com.example.app >/sdcard/memdump"+filename+".txt","exit","adb pull memdump"+i+".txt"});
```

This should give you a filename.txt having meminfo of your app. What you need here is the PSS value of your app. More the PSS value more the memory footprint of your app. Just open the file as a stream. Fetch the PSS value using a pattern search and save it in a list after every TC. This way after the test, you will have a list of PSS value at various points in your app. You can create trends/graph from that.

If its strictly a linear graph then you should delve in deeper. Other than that, it is not something you will get a lot of issues with.

**2) Write a suite which does things repeatedly and take dumpsys:**

Finding sneaky memory leaks would require you do some action repeatedly (say launch an activity 50 times)
Let's say you have a home page and you can refresh it from the menu bar.

### Now write a TC which:

- a) goes to menu bar and click's refresh button.
- b) Dump meminfo , fetch PSS and save it in a list.
- c) Repeat a
- d) Do this repeatedly, lets say 50 times, and then make a trend graph for that particular activity.

This would be a time taking suite but the trends you will get would be meaningful and should find you good issues.

I would suggest you to go with 2. Also, if anyone can suggest any improvement or another way it would be awesome.